# mpeg-dash combine multiple mpd files / dynamically generate mpd file

Tags: html5-video, http-live-streaming, mpeg-dash, mp4box

I continuously record video that is saved as single segment dash files named by the recording timestamp:

MP4Box -dash 10000 -profile onDemand -single-file -single-segment -segment-name filename_ filename.mp4

```
20161210T101010Z_20161210T101020Z_init.mp4
20161210T101010Z_20161210T101020Z_dash.mpd
20161210T101020Z_20161210T101030Z_init.mp4
20161210T101020Z_20161210T101030Z_dash.mpd
```

Users are able to specify a custom time window. I want to be able to combine all mpd files included in the timeframe, or to generate an mpd file from scratch including all available mp4 files for the specified duration.

It is easy to do so with HLS/ts files, but I could not find information on how to do it with mpeg-dash

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting you correctly, you want to be able to combine different mpd files into one ?

I think it can be done but with a different approach, which should be fairly easy. What you can do is, provide a dynamically written conf file to DashCast link [here](https://gpac.wp.imt.fr/dashcast/) and perhaps that should be able to produce a fresh single mpd when executed.

I'm not sure about the usability of the examples given in the link for your case, but you could write a script that calls DashCast and passes different parameters, per your requirements.

Lemme know how that goes,
Cheers!