# Can you have an MPEG Dash File Pointing To Other MPEG Dash Files?

Tags: mpeg-dash

I'd like to assemble an mpeg dash playlist where I splice together multiple MPEG-Dash URLS to form a single cohesive movie.

```
MPEG-Dash URL 1 Start @00:10 End @00:30
MPEG-Dash URL 2 Start @01:00 End @05:00
MPEG-Dash URL 3 Play Whole File
```

Is this possible without breaking open all the files and creating a bunch of different periods with the individual AdaptionSet/SegmentTemplates/Timelines copied from the child streams? My worry is if I open up every file individually and one of the child streams is re-formatted everything will break.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41088670/mpeg-dash-combine-multiple-mpd-files-dynamically-generate-mpd-file) mentions someone doing a dash-cast, but I'm trying to keep it in (static) MPD format since we have a player that already supports that.

Is this perhaps what `SegmentURL` is for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DASH specification supports the XML Linking Language (XLink), so you can include references to remote content such as a Period element.

Here is an example, from a [DASH test file](https://dash.akamaized.net/fokus/adinsertion-samples/xlink/threeperiods.mpd):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<MPD xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011 http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/MPEG-DASH_schema_files/DASH-MPD.xsd" profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-live:2011" minBufferTime="PT1.5S" type="static" mediaPresentationDuration="PT1M12S">
<Period xlink:href="https://se-mashup.fokus.fraunhofer.de/dashjs/period_timescapes" xlink:actuate="onLoad"></Period>
</MPD>
```